# Streaming large result sets with MySQL

Tags: java, mysql, spring, streaming

I'm developing a spring application that uses large MySQL tables. When loading large tables, I get an `OutOfMemoryException`, since the driver tries to load the entire table into application memory.

I tried using

```
statement.setFetchSize(Integer.MIN_VALUE);
```

but then every ResultSet I open hangs on `close()`; looking online I found that that happens because it tries loading any unread rows before closing the ResultSet, but that is not the case since I do this:

```
ResultSet existingRecords = getTableData(tablename);
try {
    while (existingRecords.next()) {
        // ...
    }
} finally {
    existingRecords.close(); // this line is hanging, and there was no exception in the try clause
}
```

The hangs happen for small tables (3 rows) as well, and if I don't close the RecordSet (which happened in one method) then `connection.close()` hangs.

---

Stack trace of the hang:

> SocketInputStream.socketRead0(FileDescriptor, byte[], int, int, int) line: not available [native method]
>   SocketInputStream.read(byte[], int, int) line: 129
>   ReadAheadInputStream.fill(int) line: 113
>   ReadAheadInputStream.readFromUnderlyingStreamIfNecessary(byte[], int, int) line: 160
>   ReadAheadInputStream.read(byte[], int, int) line: 188
>   MysqlIO.readFully(InputStream, byte[], int, int) line: 2428 
>   MysqlIO.reuseAndReadPacket(Buffer, int) line: 2882
>   MysqlIO.reuseAndReadPacket(Buffer) line: 2871
>   MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(int) line: 3414
>   MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket() line: 910
>   MysqlIO.nextRow(Field[], int, boolean, int, boolean, boolean, boolean, Buffer) line: 1405
>   RowDataDynamic.nextRecord() line: 413
>   RowDataDynamic.next() line: 392 
>   RowDataDynamic.close() line: 170
>   JDBC4ResultSet(ResultSetImpl).realClose(boolean) line: 7473 
>   JDBC4ResultSet(ResultSetImpl).close() line: 881 
>   DelegatingResultSet.close() line: 152
>   DelegatingResultSet.close() line: 152
>   DelegatingPreparedStatement(DelegatingStatement).close() line: 163
>   (This is my class) Database.close() line: 84

Comment: I don't think setting MIN_VALUE does something useful. How would you return at most -2^31 records?

Comment: It's a mysql thing. MySQL does not support that traditional setFetchSize, so any value is ignored except Integer.MIN_VALUE, which causes proper streaming.

Comment: Where is the close statement hanging (stack trace)? Which MySQL version are you using and which JDBC driver?

Comment: MySQL 5.1.43-community, and the driver is J/Connector. I'll try and post the stack trace of the hangs in a few minutes.

Comment: Also can I ask how was the conclusion reached that no exception was thrown? (finally blocks execute even in case of exceptions). Will it not be a better idea to catch() and print stacktrace just for debugging purposes. Perhaps there is actually an OOM thingy inside the loop?

Comment: Because in the debugger the last line was `count++;` and it got executed - and it was outside the while in a separate for loop (which was omitted because it's irrelevant)

Comment: I've added a stack trace; it looks like the driver is trying to read more lines and getting stuck.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**Don't close your `ResultSet`s twice.**

Apparently, when closing a `Statement` it attempts to close the corresponding `ResultSet`, as you can see in these two lines from the stack trace:

> DelegatingResultSet.close() line: 152
>   DelegatingPreparedStatement(DelegatingStatement).close() line: 163

I had thought the hang was in `ResultSet.close()` but it was actually in `Statement.close()` which calls `ResultSet.close()`. Since the `ResultSet` was already closed, it just hung.

We've replaced all `ResultSet.close()` with `results.getStatement().close()` and removed all `Statement.close()`s, and the problem is now solved.

Comment: Glad you fixed it. However, the normal JDBC idiom is to close the resources in **reversed** order as you acquired them. Some JDBC drivers (including MySQL one) indeed implicitly tries to close any opened "child" resources. Thus, after opening Connection, Statement and ResultSet in this order you need to close ResultSet, Statement and Connection in this order. You shouldn't leave the statement open, it may leak resources, especially when you're using connection pooling wherein the actual connection won't be directly closed. BTW: I find it odd that it threw OOME instead of SQLException.

Comment: The OOME was when not streaming; when streaming it just hung on close. The 'proper' way to do this is the first thing we tried, and the one that didn't work; we closed ResultSet, then got hung closing the statement (which tried reclosing the ResultSet). Now we only close the statement and hopefully we won't get memory leaks. Thanks for your tips

Comment: But why it hang? I meet this problem too.It spend about 30s to close.

Comment: I solve my problem.Because I use streaming with multi resultset,but I only read apart of the resultset, when close, they need consume the reset of result.

Answer (score 61):

Only setting the fetch size is not the correct approach. The [javadoc of `Statement#setFetchSize()`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#setFetchSize%28int%29) already states the following:

> *Gives the JDBC driver a **hint** as to the number of rows that should be fetched from the database*

The driver is actually free to apply or ignore the hint. Some drivers ignore it, some drivers apply it directly, some drivers need more parameters. The MySQL JDBC driver falls in the last category. If you check the [MySQL JDBC driver documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/en/connector-j-reference-implementation-notes.html), you'll see the following information (scroll about 2/3 down until header ***ResultSet***):

> To enable this functionality, you need to create a Statement instance in the following manner:
>
> ```
> stmt = conn.createStatement(java.sql.ResultSet.TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY, java.sql.ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY);
> stmt.setFetchSize(Integer.MIN_VALUE);
> ```

Please read the *entire* section of the document, it describes the caveats of this approach as well. Here's a relevant cite:

> There are some caveats with this approach. You will have to read all of the rows in the result set (or close it) before you can issue any other queries on the connection, or an exception will be thrown.
>
> (...)
>
> If the statement is within scope of a transaction, then locks are released when the transaction completes (which implies that the statement needs to complete first). As with most other databases, statements are not complete until all the results pending on the statement are read or the active result set for the statement is closed.

If that doesn't fix the `OutOfMemoryError` (not `Exception`), then the problem is likely that you're storing all the data in Java's memory instead of processing it **immediately** as soon as the data comes in. This would require more changes in your code, maybe a complete rewrite. I've answered similar question before [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2180835/handling-large-records-in-a-j2ee-application).

Comment: This seems oddly familiar; it's a copy+paste of your answer in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2095490/. And it's irrelevant since it tells me to do what I already said I did and caused me problems - in the question itself.

Comment: Why am I not allowed to copypaste the relevant parts of my own words? Further you didn't tell that you created the statement as per the MySQL JDBC document. I've seen too often that ones made the mistake to set *only* the FetchSize.

Comment: @configurator you seem to be scolding BalusC for giving you an answer (together with your downvote). +1 since I was going to answer the same thing (about the `TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY`)

Comment: @Bozho: thanks. @configuratior: where's your respons? Anyway, I just wanted to say sorry if you don't value copypastes or so, but I couldn't find the specific MySQL link within a sec, but I can find my answer within a sec, so I used it and I thought it was easy to copypaste part of it as I was going to type almost exactly the same answer. If your downvote is actually because you hate me for other (obvious?) reasons, then please say so. I have no problem to ignore you in your future questions :)

Comment: @Balus: I don't hate you; I don't even know you.
The downvote was because you told me to do the same thing I already did; the createStatement parameters you specified are even the default values. Never mind, I've retracted my downvote since you don't deserve it.

Comment: Fair enough. How about the connection being part of a bigger picture, e.g. a transaction? The docs also state that this ain't going to work. How about processing of the data? It should not be kept entirely in Java's memory.

Comment: Streaming actually works; only closing the ResultSets is the issue, which has just been solved. You can see the solution in my answer.

Comment: I'm thinking that why spring jdbc template does not support this case? I mean set "java.sql.ResultSet.TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY, java.sql.ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY" for Statement.

Comment: @ShawnGuo: sorry I don't do Spring. I only do Java EE.

Comment: even this is important : stmt.setFetchSize(Integer.MIN_VALUE); else it wont work

Comment: Yup, the documentation indeed says so.

Answer (score 4):

In case someone has the same problem, I resolved it by using the LIMIT clause in my query.

This issue was reported to MySql as a bug (find it here http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=42929) which now has a status of "not a bug". The most pertinent part is:

> There's no way currently to close a result set "midstream"

Since you have to read ALL rows, you will have to limit your query results using a clause like WHERE or LIMIT. Alternatively, try the following:

```
ResultSet rs = ...
while(rs.next()) {
   ...
   if(bailOut == true) { break; }
}

while(rs.next()); // This will deplete the remaining rows on the stream

rs.close();
```

It may not be ideal, but at least it gets you past the hang on close.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using spring jdbc then you need to use a preparedstatement creator in conjunction with SimpleJdbcTemplate to set the fetchSize as Integer.MIN_VALUE. Its described here http://neopatel.blogspot.com/2012/02/mysql-jdbc-driver-and-streaming-large.html

Answer (score 0):

It hangs because even if you stop listening, the request still goes on.
In order to close the ResultSet and Statement in the right order, try calling statement.cancel() first:

```
public void close() {
    try {
        statement.cancel();
        if (resultSet != null)
            resultSet.close();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        // ignore errors on closing
    } finally {
        try {
            statement.close();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            // ignore errors on closing
        } finally {
            resultSet = null;
            statement = null;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Scrollable Resultset ignore fetchSize and fetches all the rows at once causing out of meory error.

For me it worked properly when setting useCursors=true, otherwise The Scrollable Resultset ignores all the implementations of fetch size, in my case it was 5000 but Scrollable Resultset fetched millions of records at once causing excessive memory usage. underlying DB is MSSQLServer.

jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://localhost:1433/ACS;TDS=8.0;useCursors=true