# How to process data from large ResultSet without loading them all to memory?

Tags: java, sql, jdbc, resultset

My Database is hosting on mysql server & I'm using Java to analyze data.

My issue: after execute 'Select' query will return a 2.5 GB result set. I don't want to load all the data to memory.  So is there any ways that I could continuously retrieve data & process it?

'limit by rows' will not be an option, b/c this 2.5 GB data is joined & retrieved from 4 tables. So 'limit by rows' will increase my total run-time a lot.

I've tried statement.setFetchSize(50), but it seemed not working as I expected.

Any suggestions will be really appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: I would increase your heap size.  If you need to process 2.5 GB of data, it doesn't sound like a lot to have 8-32 GB of memory.

Comment: You want to take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2447324/streaming-large-result-sets-with-mysql

Answer (score 1):

Statement stmt = readOnlyConn.createStatement(java.sql.ResultSet.TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY,
                    java.sql.ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY);

stmt.setFetchSize(Integer.MIN_VALUE);

The code above solved my issues.  Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

> BlockquoteStatement stmt = readOnlyConn.createStatement(java.sql.ResultSet.TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY, java.sql.ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY);
>   stmt.setFetchSize(Integer.MIN_VALUE);
>   The code above solved my issues. Thanks for the help!

Yes, BUT if you are using postgres, you also have to have autocommit turned OFF! (realised after 2h of work =D )

[see postgres docs here](https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/head/query.html)

Comment: Hi Jaroslav, this does not provide an answer to the question - it really belongs as a comment on the other answer, but you will need to earn more reputation to be able to [leave comments](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment), so in the meantime you need to concentrate on posting good-quality original answers and questions which can earn you reputation.