# JDBC MySQL import GC Overhead Limit Exceeded

Tags: java, mysql, garbage-collection

I'm trying to import some data out of my MySQL database using Java, the query returns about 15mill rows and to prevent the ResultSet running out of memory I am streaming each results one by one.

```
private static void addEdges(DirectedGraph<String, DefaultEdge> g) throws SQLException {
Statement selectID = null;
String selectSQL = "SELECT citations.paperid, papers.id FROM papers INNER JOIN citations ON citations.title = papers.title AND citations.year = papers.year;";


try {
    selectID = conn.createStatement(java.sql.ResultSet.TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY, java.sql.ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY);
    selectID.setFetchSize(Integer.MIN_VALUE);
    ResultSet rs = selectID.executeQuery(selectSQL);
    String from;
    String to;
    System.out.println("iterating");
    while(rs.next()) {
    from = rs.getString("paperid");
    to = rs.getString("id");
    g.addEdge(from, to);
    }
} catch (SQLException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} finally {
    if (selectID != null) {
    try {
        selectID.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Error closing statement");
        }
    }
}
}
```

However I'm now getting this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.nextRow(MysqlIO.java:2092)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.RowDataDynamic.nextRecord(RowDataDynamic.java:406)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.RowDataDynamic.next(RowDataDynamic.java:385)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.RowDataDynamic.close(RowDataDynamic.java:163)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetImpl.realClose(ResultSetImpl.java:7472)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetImpl.close(ResultSetImpl.java:919)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.realClose(StatementImpl.java:2617)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.close(StatementImpl.java:580)
```

This is being thrown from `selectID.close()` Which is odd as the ResultSet it should be closing should only contain one row. Tried allocating more memory but this issue still occurs, any ideas?
(I'm using JGraphT library to create a directed graph)

Comment: May be because of you are created an array inside the g instance.

Comment: http://www.coderanch.com/t/304547/JDBC/databases/Resultset-million-rows

Comment: So is the ResultSet still caching the values even though I've set fetchSize() to use one row at a time?

Comment: @BradStevenson it might. Could easily be a bug in the mysql library that you are using. You have the option of using *limit*.

Comment: @BradStevenson try updating your mysql driver also..

Comment: Are you sure you want to set the fetch size to a huge negative number: selectID.setFetchSize(Integer.MIN_VALUE) ? Have you tried selectID.setFetchSize(1) or similar?

Comment: @Eugene The query already takes a huge amount of time to complete so using limit would have to be a last resort at the moment. I was using mysql-connector-java-5.1.29 I will try with it upgraded to 5.1.30 unless there are any preferable drivers?

Comment: @GeoffWilliams I'm using MIN_VALUE because setFetchSize() wasn't honouring its value if I used another value. I think its a common issue and solution

Comment: Thanks @BradStevenson - interesting.  Looked it up and found this, don't know if it helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2447324/streaming-large-result-sets-with-mysql

Comment: @GeoffWilliams Setting the fetchSize to `Integer.MIN_VALUE` is the only way to prevent the MySQL driver from loading all rows at once.

Comment: Are you sure the problem isn't simply that the graph datastructure you are creating in memory is getting too large?