# Streaming MySql ResultSet with fixed number of results at a time

Tags: java, mysql, sql

I have MySql table with 16 millions records, because of some migration work I'm reading whole Mysql table.

The following code is used for streaming large ResultSet in MySql

```
        statement = connection.createStatement(
                java.sql.ResultSet.TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY,
                java.sql.ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY);
        statement.setFetchSize(Integer.MIN_VALUE);
```

but this is streaming one result at a time , does it mean we are hitting MySql server for each row

while using streaming can we set something like this statement.setFetchSize(1000);

I want to reduce number of round trips to server while streaming large ResultSet

Comment: read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2447324/streaming-large-result-sets-with-mysql?rq=1 more similar

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I will assume that you are using the official MySQL provided JDBC driver Connector/J.

You are explicitly telling JDBC (and MySQL) to stream the results row-by-row with `statement.setFetchSize(Integer.MIN_VALUE);`

From [MYSQL Docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/es/connector-j-reference-implementation-notes.html):

> By default, ResultSets are completely retrieved and stored in memory.
>   In most cases this is the most efficient way to operate, and due to
>   the design of the MySQL network protocol is easier to implement. If
>   you are working with ResultSets that have a large number of rows or
>   large values, and can not allocate heap space in your JVM for the
>   memory required, you can tell the driver to stream the results back
>   one row at a time.
>
> To enable this functionality, you need to create a Statement instance
>   in the following manner:
>
> ```
> stmt = conn.createStatement(java.sql.ResultSet.TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY,
>           java.sql.ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY);
> stmt.setFetchSize(Integer.MIN_VALUE);
> ```
>
> The combination of a forward-only, read-only result set, with a fetch
>   size of Integer.MIN_VALUE serves as a signal to the driver to stream
>   result sets row-by-row. After this any result sets created with the
>   statement will be retrieved row-by-row.

Any value other than `Integer.MIN_VALUE` for the fetch size is ignored by MySQL, and the standard behavior applies. The entire result set will be fetched by the JDBC driver.

Either don't use `setFetchSize()`, so the JDBC driver will use the default value (`0`), or set the value to `0` explicitly. Using the value of `0` will also ensure that JDBC doesn't use MySQL cursors, which may occur depending on your MySQL and Connector/J versions and configuration.

Comment: that means there is no way to load 1000 or so rows at a time while doing streaming am I right??

Comment: You're going to have to be specific what you mean when you say "streaming". Please show some code.

Comment: I'm asking instead of doing stream resultset row by row can we stream 1000 rows at a time

Answer (score 3):

To fetch with a fixed number of records at a time (e.g. batches of 1000) instead of record by record streaming with the MySQL JDBC driver, you need to either:

1. Set **useCursorFetch** to true and **defaultFetchSize** to desired batch size in your JDBC URL e.g.

   ```
   jdbc:mysql://localhost/?useCursorFetch=true&defaultFetchSize=1000
   ```
2. As per the MySQL driver documentation, set **useCursorFetch** to true in the JDBC URL and then call setFetchSize(1000) after creating the statement. See code below:

   ```
   conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/?useCursorFetch=true", "user", "s3cr3t");
   stmt = conn.createStatement();
   stmt.setFetchSize(1000);
   rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM your_table_here");
   ```

See official documentation for more info: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/8.0/en/connector-j-reference-implementation-notes.html