# How to check if resultset has records returned w/o moving the cursor in Java

Tags: java, jdbc, resultset

I am wondering how to check if the resultset has some records returned, just like below,

```
while(((ResultSet) rs).next()){
    ((ResultSet) rs).previous();
    return true;
}
```

But I can't do this since the result set type is TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY, is there any handy API available for my case? wasNull is not the right one for certain, thank you for any pointers!

Even

Comment: After doing the very first rs.next() you are still on the vey first row. Why do you want to stay before the very first row ?

Comment: maybe it can help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1870022/java-resultset-hasnext

Comment: i don't think I am still on the very first row after next(), the cursor moves forward already, but this part of loop logic should NOT affect the real result set reading process later, that's why I need to rewind it back to the begining

Answer (score 4):

```
 if(!resultSet.isBeforeFirst()){
   System.out.println("resultset contin no rows");
 }
```

isBeforeFirst() returns true if the cursor is before the first row; false if the cursor is at any other position or the result set contains no rows

Answer (score 1):

The answer is, you can't. That the nature of SQL row sets: You are notified when you hit the end, but you don't know until you *try* to get the next record and there isn't one. It's just the way it is.

Answer (score 0):

Since you can not know before you make the `rs.next()` move about the state of your ResultSet you could probably:

1. run a `count` statement before your create your ResultSet or
2. do a first `rs.next()`, or `rs.first()` and use its contents in case your set is not empty like
   this:

   ```
           boolean state = rs.first(); // or rs.next();
           if (state == false)
               System.out.println("empty");
           else {
               System.out.println("not empty");
               while (state) {
                   System.out.println(rs.getInt(1));
                   // use your row ...
                   state = rs.next();
               }
           }
   ```

Answer (score -1):

If your first call to `rs.next()` is successful and it returned true, that means there are some records returned.

Comment: I know, the problem is I can't move the cursor back and forth because SQLException is caught,  Result set type is TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY..