# Is it possible to tell if a java ResultSet is empty without affecting the record?

Tags: java

I do not want to use next() since if the ResultSet is not empty, I do not want the cursor to be advanced. Is there some sort of peek() method or equivalent that will return false if the ResultSet is empty and true otherwise without affecting the record?

Edit:

I cannot call `beforeFirst` because I get the following

> Operation requires a scrollable ResultSet, but this ResultSet is
>   FORWARD_ONLY

I need `FORWARD_ONLY` because I'm using postgreSQL cursors

Comment: See also [How to check if resultset has records returned w/o moving the cursor in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6722285/how-to-check-if-resultset-has-records-returned-w-o-moving-the-cursor-in-java)

Comment: Why can't you create a scroll insensitive `ResultSet`? All it takes is a `Statement stmt = con.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE);`.

Comment: @SanjayT.Sharma That statement will fail as you also need to provide its concurrency model: `Statement query = conn.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE, ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);`

Answer (score 2):

`isBeforeFirst()` returns `true` if the cursor is before the first row or `false` if it is in any other position or the resultset is empty.

Check out the [Java API for ResultSet for isBeforeFirst()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#isBeforeFirst%28%29)

Answer (score 1):

You can invoke the `first()` method to check if you have results in the `ResultSet`. If `first()` returns true, you can then call `beforeFirst()` to reset the `ResultSet` cursor position.

Comment: That's what I'm doing, and there's where I get the `Operation requires a scrollable ResultSet, but this ResultSet is FORWARD_ONLY` exception

Answer (score -2):

```
   getFetchSize()
```

based on the size returned you can proceed...

Comment: The fetch size has nothing to do with the size of the resultset, plus if your purpose was to get the size of the result and stop further processing if there were none, you could have explained it, too.